# Is this initial value problem well-defined for all $T>0$?

Tags: initial-value-problems

Is this initial value problem well-defined for every $T>0$?

$$y’(t)=-t^2y\cos(t)$$
$$y(0)=2$$

where $t\in[0,T]$.

I know that since $f(y,t)= -t^2y\cos(t)$ and its derivative $f_y(y,t)$ are continuous functions everywhere, there exists an interval $[0,T]$ in which the problem is well-defined. However, I’m not sure how to find the value of $T$.

Update: I found the solution $y(t) = 2 e^{-(t^2 - 2) \sin(t) - 2 t \cos(t)}$, but I’d like to know if there’s a way to obtain $T$ without previously calculating it.

Comment: Why don't you solve it?

Comment: @mattos I think I know how to solve it, but would that give me the value of $T$?

Comment: I found $y(t)=2e^{-(t^2-2) \sin (t) - 2 t \cos (t)}$.

Comment: @mattos No, I don’t know how to do it! (I updated the question)

Comment: You have $T = \infty$.

Comment: @mattos How do you know that?

Comment: Do you see any values of $t$ that might make $y$ 'blow up' i.e go to infinity?

Comment: @mattos Okay, thank you! Is there a way of finding $T$ without calculating the solution though?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I don't know of any theorems that can give it to you directly for an arbitrary ODE, though it's been a while since I learned these things. The [Picard-Lindelof theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) (which you seemed to be applying originally) just tells you there exists an interval which the solution exists and is unique. It doesn't tell you the maximal size of the interval. Maybe see the 'unicity' section of [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Maximum_domain_of_solution).